# npm install error ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty,

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

I encountered the following error when I tried to install some new packages using `npm install`. It happened when I did `npm install a-new-package --save` and then delete package-lock.json file afterwards to refresh everything.

```
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /Users/memphismeng/Documents/React Programming/Foot-in-The-Door/mobile/fitd/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators
npm ERR! dest /Users/memphismeng/Documents/React Programming/Foot-in-The-Door/mobile/fitd/node_modules/@babel/.plugin-proposal-decorators-ysLLPQFw
npm ERR! errno -66
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/Users/memphismeng/Documents/React Programming/Foot-in-The-Door/mobile/fitd/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators' -> '/Users/memphismeng/Documents/React Programming/Foot-in-The-Door/mobile/fitd/node_modules/@babel/.plugin-proposal-decorators-ysLLPQFw'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/memphismeng/.npm/_logs/2021-06-15T18_07_01_162Z-debug.log
```

What went wrong? I also tried `npm audit fix --legacy-peer-deps` but it didn't work.

Comment: Just remove `.plugin-proposal-decorators-ysLLPQFw` from `node_modules`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

May be deleting `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file and then reinstalling `npm` would resolve your issue.

So, consider the following commands to apply the above operations:

```
npm remove node_modules 
npm remove package-lock.json
npm install
```

Comment: This is happening with a global module for me.. any ideas?

Comment: this happens when there is an interruption during installing package i think, for global find the global node_module and delete the dir package you are installing.
as for me that I am using NVM, I went to .nvm/versions/node/<node version which you are getting error>/lib/node_modules and deleted the package that was trying to install.

Comment: This solution works but when my internet was incredibly slow it didn't. Please confirm you have a decent internet speed before you go ahead with this solution. It works.

Comment: This worked for me, but manually deleting the node_modules folder, because the (npm remove node_modules) command gave me an error. Then I used the second command:
npm remove package-lock.json. I didn't have to use npm install. I think the npm remove package-lock.json command installed everything anew.

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules` works better. Note that removing `package-lock.json` would mean you're losing the exact versions you're locked onto, and you're getting the latest versions instead. Most of the time this is fine, but watch out for potential issues.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem while having a **slow and unreliable Internet connection**. I created this script that can be run with `bash` that fixes all of the interrupted installs:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

while true; do
  log="$HOME/.npm/_logs/`ls $HOME/.npm/_logs/ | tail -n 1`"
  echo "log: $log"
  for path in `cat "$log" | grep 'ENOTEMPTY' | grep -oE "[^']+node_modules[^']+"`; do
    echo "removing $path"
    rm -rf "$path"
  done
  if npm install; then
    break
  fi
done
```

Basically, I use the approach from https://stackoverflow.com/a/69668434/1320237 but I just had too much do deal with manually.

Note: While it looks to me like it has a `O(n * n)` run time, it might have a `O(n)` download time for `n = number of packages`. So it is useful for slow Internet. You might be faster to just delete the `node_modules` directory if your Internet connection is fast.

Comment: My internet was crappy and this saved my day!

Comment: This script was like a live saver :) thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Obviously, the deleting of package.json is working but this is not always the desired solution. Sometimes you want to run:

```
 npm i --package-lock-only //to update package.lock.json
 npm audit fix
```

and then:

```
npm i
```

And this should be the first try but, I don't know why it didn't work in my case, which is in react native scenario. It seems like the error "npm install error ENOTEMPTY" is happening when the npm try to write to a folder that is not empty and in this case to "node_modules/@babel/.plugin-proposal-decorators-ysLLPQFw". If you run:

```
rm -rf node_modules/@babel/.plugin-proposal-decorators-ysLLPQFw
```

And then:

```
npm i
```

It should work this time. It should be a cleanup process of react-native though, and when working with web starter kit like CRA it never happened to me before.

Comment: But the problem with this is, once it deleted, then new node module error will start coming. I manually deleted around 10+ packages, but it keeps coming with new one. Is there any automatic solution to this ?

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when the npm commands(like install, audit fix, etc) get terminated before completion due to any reason.
For me, the solution was to completely delete node_modules folder and run "npm install" again.
Optionally, you could also try deleting only the directory inside the node_modules which throws the error.

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules` :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a quite similar issue while working with npm.
What worked like a charm for me was updating my packages & dependencies for the project, specifically `react-scripts`.

Check what are your outdated packages with:

```
npm outdated
```

Or, follow the code snippets of [this guy in medium,](https://jh3y.medium.com/how-to-update-all-npm-packages-in-your-project-at-once-17a8981860ea) that automates the task of check and update your packages one by one.

Answer (score 0):

just go to same package name directory and delete it and install it again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was making a NPM module that I was installing globally on my computer. This is the issue I ran into.

The core of my issue was having a `script` in my `package.json` called `install`.

**THIS OVERRIDES THE `npm install` command!**

```json
{
  "name": "foo",
  "main": "index.js",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    // OVERRIDES `npm i` ❗
    //  just use a different name
    "install": "npm pack && npm i -g foo-1.0.tgz"
  },
}
```

I fixed it by renaming `install` to `build` and then deleting my package's `node_modules` doing `npm i`.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the folder containing shadcn as listed in the terminal and deleted both the shadcn-ui folder and the shacn-ui hidden folder. Then retried "npx shadcn-ui@latest init" and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem  but with npx . when i want to create new react app it shows me the same error. i go to the directory ,that in error was and  i created new npm folder in :

> C:\Users"YOURUSER"\Roaming\AppData\

and after that it work for me .

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred because you are not in the right direction of the project.
make sure you are in the right file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the previous installation was interrupted or otherwise failed (for example due to poor internet connection)

The solution is to just delete the `node_modules` folder and re-install. You **do not** need to delete your lockfile.

```bash
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Alternatively, you might be able to just delete the broken folders so that the installation will be:

```bash
rm -rf node_modules/.* node_modules/@*/.*
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

### In my nextjs project,this solved me:

1. deleting the .next folder
2. deleting package.json
3. npm run build again