# Trying to install animate.css with npm, but keep getting errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, animation, css-animations, animate.css

I am trying to install animate.css with npm. But it is showing me a lot of error. I am new to javascript and node, I am trying to build a resume website. Here is a picture of all the errors. [image]

Comment: Try yarn add animate.css

Comment: maybe this could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67991537/npm-install-error-enotempty-directory-not-empty

Comment: do you have babel in your project?

Comment: @Deotyma, no I don't think so, I have installed babel, do I need it? how do I check?

Comment: @DiD thank you very much npm didn't worked, install yarn and it worked

Answer (score 1):

After I installed animate.css in the way below

```
npm install animate.css --save
```

I simply had to import the CSS file like this from my node_modules:

```
@import "~animate.css/animate.css";
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

ror: "directory not empty".
This means that files already exist in this folder. Just stop your terminal, delete the folder (which is in node_modules) and run again. If it doesn't work, restart your PC and try again.