# npm install behaving abnormally

Tags: reactjs, node.js, react-native, npm, node-modules

I'm trying to install npm packages in my react native prjoect and when I run **npm install**, packages are installed with random strings added. What could be the problem with my npm. Example is **.plugin-
bugfix-safari-id-destructuring-collision-in-function-expression-IZ2YO8TM'**, also it breaks my project too. When i delete node_modules folder, I can't install packages again.It tries to rename the package too

```
npm ERR! path 
/Users/user/Documents/Mobile_Apps/project/node_modules/@babel/plugin-bugfix- 
safari-id-destructuring-collision-in-function-expression
npm ERR! dest 
/Users/user/Documents/Mobile_Apps/project/node_modules/@babel/.plugin- 
bugfix-safari-id-destructuring-collision-in-function-expression-IZ2YO8TM
npm ERR! errno -66
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename 
'/Users/user/Documents/Mobile_Apps/project/node_modules/@babel/plugin- 
bugfix-safari-id-destructuring-collision-in-function-expression' -> 
'/Users/user/Documents/Mobile_Apps/project/node_modules/@babel/.plugin- 
bugfix-safari-id-destructuring-collision-in-function-expression-IZ2YO8TM'
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting your `node_modules` **and** `package-lock.json` and then doing `npm install` again?  Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/q/67991537/1563833

Comment: I tried but it failed,

Comment: What do I have to do to reproduce this problem?  Create a new folder and a new module and gradually start npm installing each module you need until you either find the one that breaks everything or it all gets successfully installed.

Answer (score 0):

So I realised there was a package that was being installed directly with git url, once I removed the package, deleted node_modules and run npm install. Everything was back to normal. I hope this will also help other people.